# Can't easily set property to Null when editing an entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

In my asp.net core app with EF6, I have a hard time setting a property to Null. For example:

```
public Class A { public int Id {get; set;} public virtual B B{ get;set; } }
public Class B { public int Id {get; set;} }

//in edit method in controller:

var db_a = dbContext.A_entities
.Include(x => x.B) //if this line isn't there, then setting to null doesn't work
.Single(x => x.Id == form_a.Id);
if (form_a.B == null) {
 db_a.B = null; //this doesn't save to db unless we use .Include() above.
}

//...

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

In the above, if I have 10 properties, or if B happens to have certain properties, then it becomes cumbersome to use .Include for every property. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to delete the relationship between A and B, or you want to the B in the table B?

Answer (score 1):

You are reaching `B` using foreign key (relation) through A, EF does a lazy loading and does not actually load all `B`s for each `A`, using `Include` tell it to eager load `B` so it actually loads and you can set its value.

however if you don't need `A` and just want to set its `B` value to null do something like this:

```
var b = dbContext.A_entities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == form_a.Id)?.B;
if (form_a.B == null) b = null;
```

Comment: i definitely need A as I need to edit A and all its properties.  Editing properties works unless I set them to null, in which case  I have to use .Include().

Comment: using include before the update worked for me. It makes sense:  the model's FKs were loaded as null because include wasn't specified, therefore if null was sent back to the server; no change would be detected on the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the relationship between A and B, you could try to define the foreignkey in A like

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AName { get; set; }
    public int? BId { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
```

And, then when deleting the relationship, you just need to set the `BId` as null

```
var a = _context.A.FirstOrDefault();
a.BId = null;
_context.SaveChanges();
```